# URL Rewrite Replace first ? with &

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I've got an htaccess file that's a bit bulky, but here's the rewrite code that affects this question:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|upload|gyazo|image|short)
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/? admin.php?p=$1
```

What I wanted to know is if there was a way to rewrite a url in such a way so that the first parameter after my rewrite parameters can use a question mark instead of an ampersand.

so that I can write urls like this

```
http://mydomain.com/admin/page?example=true&param2=false
```

when really the page requested would be something like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/admin.php?p=page&example=true&param2=false
```

and so on.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` should work as it is. Just add [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag and query string will be appened to admin.php?p=$1&...

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/? admin.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```